# scraping messages from a forum

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, findall

well here is my problem, so I want to store data from a *forum(messages+id)* and I succeeded to scrape only the messages that are not a response of a previous message if u can help me, here is my code

here is the link of the forum:

http://forum.doctissimo.fr/medicaments/Neuroleptiques/souhaite-arreter-vousdes-sujet_953_1.htm

example(HTML) of a message that is a response of a previous message

```
<div itemprop="text">
  <p></p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="citation reducible-citation"><b class="s1"><a href="http://forum.doctissimo.fr/medicaments/Neuroleptiques/souhaite-arreter-vousdes-sujet_953_1.htm#t9835" class="Topic">aut49zm a écrit :</a></b>
      <div class="forum-quote-content">tjs RAS</div>
      <div class="expand-quote" style="display: none;">Afficher plus</div>
      <div class="reduce-quote">Afficher moins</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p><br><br><br>Ca fait 2 semaines aujourd'hui que je l'ai arrêté et RAS. Ca devrait être pareil pour toi &nbsp;<img title=":)" alt=":)" src="http://images.doctissimo.fr/generated/merged/flat/design/smilies/smile.gif" class="wysiwyg_smiley"> </p>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

example(HTML) of a normal message:

```
<div id="para9835" class="post_content">
  <div itemprop="text">tjs RAS
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="edited">
```

here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request


page=urllib.request.urlopen("http://forum.doctissimo.fr/medicaments/Neuroleptiques/souhaite-arreter-vousdes-sujet_953_1.htm") 

strpage=page.read().decode(page.headers.get_content_charset())
soup=BeautifulSoup(strpage,'html.parser')

for e in soup.findAll('br'):
    e.extract()

u=soup.prettify()
v=soup.findAll('div','post_content')
```

Answer (score 0):

My French is not that good (and that's an understatement...) so from the way the page is designed it's sometimes hard to tell which message is top level and which is a response, but I believe that this code should get you there:

```
for e in soup.find_all('div',class_='post_content'):
for j in  e:
    if not e.find('div',class_='citation'):
        print(j.text)
```

I'm really curious to see if this works....

Answer (score 0):

well i found it after 48 hours  straight (im starting in web scraping) .

```py
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib.request
    page=urllib.request.urlopen("http://forum.doctissimo.fr/medicaments/Neuroleptiques   /souhaite-arreter-vousdes-sujet_953_1.htm")
     soupe = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
 
       elem1 = soupe.find_all('div', attrs={'itemprop': 'text'})
     #print(elem1)
    for elem2 in elem1:
        print("-"*50)
        print(elem2.text)
        print("-"*50)
```